# How to count the duplicate value in output in new worksheet using VBA Module

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count the duplicate value in new worksheet from the source worksheet "Rawdata" using VBA module. The Number of times the same values are repeated in particular column in front of ID in different sheet.

I have done by Pivot Table but I would like to do this by VBA module on button click event.

Original Source Page

[image]

Expected Output worksheet as below :
[image]

**I have tried with the below code by updating the correct sheet name but I am getting the type mismatch error as below :**

[image]

I am using the below code but I have manually copy the whole column data from position "Y" (25) to number One ("A") by inserting new column.

modified worksheet

[image]

```
Option Explicit

 Sub CountDuplicates()

Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, e As Variant
  Dim d As Object
  Dim i As Long
  
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  d.CompareMode = 1
  
  b = Sheets("Rawdata").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1).Value
  
  ReDim Preserve b(1 To UBound(b), 1 To 2)
  a = Sheets("Rawdata").UsedRange.Value
  
  For Each e In a
  
    If Len(e) > 0 Then
      d(e) = d(e) + 1
    End If
    
  Next e
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(b)
    b(i, 2) = d(b(i, 1))
  Next i
  
  Sheets("DuplicateCount").Range("A1:B1").Resize(UBound(b)).Value = b
End Sub
```

**Now my Output result worksheet have repeat count (not distinct). I mean ID column is not unique. The numeric value have duplicated with count in result in spite of change the format to text in source column **

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Maciej I am new in VBA. I have created it by Pivot table but we need it by vba module So we can repeat it on different excel sheet and done by click event.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it accomplished. Change the sheet names according to yours.

```
Option Explicit

 Sub CountDuplicates()

  Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, e As Variant
  Dim d As Object
  Dim i As Long
  
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  d.CompareMode = 1
  
  b = Sheets("Rawdata").Range("Y3:Y10000").Value
  
  ReDim Preserve b(1 To UBound(b), 1 To 2)
  a = Sheets("Rawdata").UsedRange.Value
  
  For Each e In a
  
    If Len(e) > 0 Then
      d(e) = d(e) + 1
    End If
    
  Next e
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(b)
    b(i, 2) = d(b(i, 1))
  Next i
  
  Sheets("DuplicateCount").Range("A1:B1").Resize(UBound(b)).Value = b
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I have tried the above code by changes the sheet name with the actual one. I am getting the type mismatch error at below line :
 ReDim Preserve b(1 To UBound(b), 1 To 2)

Comment: Dear Hafiz thanks for quick reply. Its almost working but in created the worksheet "DuplicateCount" have the 1st Column is wrong. Its displaying column number 1st "A" instead of column number 25 "Y". How to fix the correct column ?

Comment: I really do not understand. Above code takes `Sheets("Rawdata").Range("Y3")` entire column and then paste unique values in `Sheets("DuplicateCount").Range("A")` and count in `Sheets("DuplicateCount").Range("B")` you can change the reference to any column like `Sheets("DuplicateCount").Range("Y1:Z1").Resize(UBound(b)).Value = b`

Comment: Actually its copy the column number One or "A" from the origin sheet insted of column "Y" or 25 and paste in duplicate sheet on 1st column "A". example the value of column "A" is CASE-2021-4306
CASE-2021-4305
CASE-2021-4304
CASE-2021-4304
CASE-2021-4303
CASE-2021-4302
CASE-2021-4301
CASE-2021-4301
 I need it to be 
NV2142
Does not turn on
NV2101
NV2103
2142
2142
NV2784
NV2651

Comment: Change this line `b = Sheets("Rawdata").Range("Y3").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1).Value` to  `b = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y1:Y10000").Value`

Comment: My friend sorry for late reply. I am still facing some Issue. I have manually copy the entire column from position "Y" or number 25 to position 1 (Create new column and copy the data from Y position.). Then Result seems to be OK but the ID or main value is not unique. Its repeated with count value.  I have added your updated source code with Screen shot of source and output worksheet. Actually I don't want to manually copy. Its default take only 1st column irrespective of what column number defined.

Comment: Can you please share the file with an example data where you want it to work on column "Y" because i tested it and works for me.